# Calculating the probability of rolling a 6 3 times in a row in the first 100 rolls [Using python]

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I am not sure how I would effectively calculate the probability without implementing many many many loops inside of loops.  I was able to execute it properly.  But there must surely be a better way to write the code. I am not sure if I should include all my code with the loops because it is very long.

code I have so far

```
import math

arr=[]
total = 0
count =0
# for k in range(1,7):
#     for i in range(1,7):
#         tupple = (k,i)
#         arr.append(tupple)
#         count+=1
def countConsecutive(array, lengthOfArray):

 
     for i in range(lengthOfArray - 2):
 
         # If consecutive elements are same
         if (array[i] == array[i + 1]==array[i+2]6):
             return True
         else:
             return False
                
     
for a in range(1,7):
    for b in range(1,7):
        for c in range(1,7):
            for d in range(1,7):
                for e in range(1,7):
                    for f in range(1,7):
                        for g in range(1,7):
                            for h in range(1,7):
                                for i in range(1,7):
                                    for j in range(1,7):
                                        for k in range(1,7):
                                            for l in range(1,7):
                                                for m in range(1,7):
                                                    for n in range(1,7):
                                                        for o in range(1,7):
                                                            for p in range(1,7):
                                                                for q in range(1,7):
                                                                    for r in range(1,7):
                                                                        for s in range(1,7):
                                                                            for t in range(1,7):
                                                                                for u in range(1,7):
                                                                                    for v in range(1,7):
                                                                                        for w in range(1,7):
                                                                                            for x in range(1,7):
                                                                                                for y in range(1,7):
                                                                                                    for z in range(1,7):
                                                                                                        for aa in range(1,7):
                                                                                                            for ab in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                for ac in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                    for ad in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                        for ae in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                            for  ad in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                for  ae in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                    for  af in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                        for  ag in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                            for  ah in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                for  ai in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                    for  aj in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                        for  ak in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                            for  al in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                for  am in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                    for  an in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                        for  ao in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                            for  ap in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                for  aq in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                    for  ar in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                        for  As in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                            for  at in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                for  av in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  aw in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  ax in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  ay in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  az in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  ba in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  bb in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  bc in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  bd in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  be in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  bf in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  bg in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  bh in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  bi in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  bj in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  bk in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  bl in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  bm in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  bn in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  bo in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  bp in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  bq in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  br in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  bs in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  bt in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  bu in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  bv in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  bw in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  bx in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  by in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  bz in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  ca in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  cb in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  cc in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  cd in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  ce in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  cf in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  cg in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  ch in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  ci in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  cj in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  ck in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  cl in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  cm in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  cn in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for  co in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for  cp in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for  cq in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                for  cr in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for cs in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for ct in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            for cu in range(1,7):
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                arr1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,q,x,y,z,aa,ab,ac,af,ae,af,ag,ah,ai,aj,ak,al,am,an,ao,ap,aq,ar,As,at,av,aw,ax,ay,az,ba,bb,bc,bd,be,bf,bg,bh,bi,bj,bk,bl,bm,bn,bo,bp,bq,br,bs,bt,bu,bv,bw,bx,by,bz,ca,cb,cc,cd,ce,cf,cg,ch,ci,cj,ck,cl,cm,cn,co,cp,cq,cr,cs,ct,cu]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                if countConsecutive(arr1,len(arr1)) == True:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    count+=1
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                arr.append(arr1)                               


                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                            
         
                                                                                        
    






print(count/pow(6,100))
```

Comment: If you think I should include the code I have I will.

Comment: Yes, please provide us with code of what you made so far.

Comment: don't say I didn't warn you about the length

Comment: Will you add the link for main algorithm? I can't understand this too much loops wants to do.

Comment: I am trying to loop through all the possible outcomes and only count those outcomes that return true from the countConsecutive function.

Comment: The only other way I can think of doing this is with a loop and many many many if statements

Comment: You can directly calculate such probabilities. Do you actually have to use a looping / sampling approach?

Comment: i don't know how to do that I  am just a beginner

Comment: In order to get the probability you need a mathematical equation. Doing it this way will just give you the result of 100 rolls, The more you did those 100 rolls and took the average of those 100 rolls the closer you'd get to an approximation of the probability, but never the actual probability. Other than that: define 3 times in a row. Is 6666 counted as twice 3 times 6 in a row, because 666 6 and 6 666? Or is it 666 and then your 3 times in a row count is reset? And this can be do with just 1 loop.

Comment: 666 would be a count of 1 if it is 666666 it would be a count of 2 6666 would just be a count of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any coded virtual experiment for this. That probability is easily calculated.

If you think scenario you take three dice and roll them probability to get three six is (1/6)³ = 1/216. So probability to not have three six is 215/216. If you repeat that hundred times probability to not have all three dice to six even once is (215/216)^100 ≃ 0.6287. So probability to have three six with 100 rolls is 1-0.6287 = 0.3713 ≃ 37.1%.

Scenario where you roll a die hundred times and check if there is three consecutive is almost the same. Slightly smaller because first two rolls it is impossible to have consecutive sixs, so basicly we have 98 tries. 1 - (215/216)^98 ≃ 0.3654 ≃ 36.5%

If you want to write code to test, here is one option.

```py
import random
def try100rolls():
  """
  Returns true if there is three consecutive sixs 
  """
  sixcount = 0
  for i in range(100):
    if random.randint(1,6) == 6:
      sixcount += 1
      if sixcount == 3:
         return True
    else:
       sixcount = 0
  return False


def test(times):
  """
  Do hundred roll test n times. Returns persentage how many times you got three six on row
  """
  successcount=0
  for i in range(times):
    if try100rolls():
       successcount += 1
  return successcount/times
```

The more test runs you do the closer result should get to mathematically calculated value. For some reason i got a slightly smaller probabilities when running 100 test runs than right values. It may be related to Python random class or I've calculated something wrong. Or it is just by change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more simple approach:

```
import  random

sixs = []
counter = 0
for i in range(100):
    for x in range(3):
        if random.randint(1,6) == 6:
            sixs.append(x)
    if len(sixs) == 3:
        counter = counter +1
    sixs = []
print(str(counter) + "%")
```

Import module `random`. And create empty `list`, in this case `sixs[]` and `counter`. `For` loop will run 100 times and inside `for` loop you will have another `for` lopp that will run 3 times and  check `if  random.randint(1,6) == 6:`. If generated `random` number is 6, `append` it to `sixs[] list`. when 2nd loop is finished it will check if number 6 is appended 3 times, if it is, it will increase `counter` by 1. At the end of the code it will print precentage.

[EDIT]

Just one more line of code is missing, to reset `list` back to 0 at the end of itteration.  That  line is `sixs[] = []`

Comment: Will the random test all numbers from 1-6 or will it just do random numbers from 1-6

Comment: In 2nd for loop it will generate random integer from 1-6 . It will check if generated number is equal to 6. If it is, It will append it to list. 2nd loop will run 3 times. When 2nd loop is finished, it will check if list have 3 numbers inside (it means that 3 times in a row number 6 was randomly generated), and if it does it will increase counter  by 1. So It will test only if number is equal to 6. If you want to test more numbers, then  create variable and set it equal to generation of random int. After that test if that variable is equal to number you wish.

Comment: I cannot see how your method works. It never resets `sixs` variable, so once you've had six three times, no matter if they are consecutive or not, your code adds one to counter in every loop.

Comment: And even if it did reset that counter, that would not work right. The question is about having three six in a row when rolling die hundred time. Your code repeats hundred times trying throw die three times. Those are two different scenarios.

Comment: Yes , agree now I see it. I need to add just one more line of code to reset sixs list to 0. @ex4 thank you for noticing.